# PyQT - Run script with button click after checkbox was selected

Tags: python-2.7, checkbox, pyqt4

I have an issue trying to accomplish this situation.

I created a form with PyQt4 with a checkbox and a button. Program will run the script if you click execute and the checkbox has been toggle.

Can you please help me with that?

Sorry, Inglish is not my native lenguage

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWuEh.png)

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import subprocess 

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):
    super(Window, self).__init__()
    self.setGeometry(200, 200, 200, 200)
    self.setWindowTitle("Learning")
    self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('pythonlogo.png'))



    self.home()

def home(self):
    btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Execute", self)
    btn.clicked.connect(self.execute)
    btn.resize(btn.minimumSizeHint())
    btn.move(110,160)

    checkBox = QtGui.QCheckBox('Run script?', self)
    #checkBox.isChecked.connect(self)


    self.show()

def execute(self):
    if checkBox.isChecked():
        subprocess.Popen("script.py 1", shell=True)

def run():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```